# Continuous functions (topology)

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: (X, \tau_x) \rightarrow (Y, \tau_y)$ a closed and open application. Let $\varphi: (X, \tau_x) \rightarrow ([0,1], \tau_{us})$ continuous ($\tau_{us}$ is the usual topology in $\mathbb{R}$). Show that the function $\forall y \in Y; \phi(y) = \sup \left\lbrace{\varphi(x) : f(x) = y }\right\rbrace$ is continuous.

Considering $y \in Y$ and an open set $V_y$ such that $\phi(y) \in V_y$. Let $x'$ be an element in $X$ such that $f(x') = y$ and $\varphi(x') \geq \varphi(x) $ for all $x$ that $f(x) =y$; and for all $\epsilon > 0$, exists $x''$ such that $\varphi(x'') > \varphi(x') - \epsilon$; and $f(x'') = y$. Then, $\varphi(x') = \phi(y) \in V_y$. The function $\varphi$ is continuous so exists $E \in E_{x'}$ (set which contains all open neighborhoods of $x'$) such that $\varphi(E) \subseteq V_y$. And $f$ is an open and closed application, so $f(N)$ is an open neighborhood for $y$.
My question is: Is it true that $\phi(f(N)) \subseteq V_y$? How can I prove that?

Comment: You seem to be assuming the existence of a maximum $x'$ in the definition of $\phi(y)$. I can't see any reason for it to exist, though I don't have a counterexample to hand.

Comment: Is not the maximum, is the supreme. And it exists because the problem defines the function $\phi$ that way.

Comment: What is $N$?..........

Comment: @MihaelArceBaldo Sure, but how do you know that there's an element $x' \in X$ such that $\phi(x')$ is equal to that supremum? If the supremum is not a maximum, then no such $x'$ will exist.

Comment: You are right, maybe I need to make a sequence right?